# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for String

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am new to angular2 and i am stuck with this error.
I have a class like this

```
@Injectable()
export class VehicleDetails {
    constructor(private policynumber: string, private vinnumber: string) {
        this.policyNumber = policynumber,
            this.vinNumber = vinnumber
    }
    policyNumber: string;
    vinNumber: string;
}
```

and another class like this

```
export class Policy {
    constructor() {
    }
    emailAddress: string;
    vehicleDetails: VehicleDetails[]
}
```

i have imported my class in the modules like this

```
import { Policy } from './models/Policy';
import { VehicleDetails } from './models/VehicleDetails';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LienholderComponent,
    AppComponent,
    PolicyVehicleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      APP_ROUTES,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    BrowserModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [Policy, VehicleDetails],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when i comment my constructor in the VehicleDetails class everything works fine, but when i use the contructor, i start to get this error.
how to resolve this error, i have two string parameter in the constructor because i would like to add the values dynamically .

my error is this

[image]

> What i want to achieve constructing the VehicleDetails class like this
>   is

```
this.policy.emailAddress='email@test.com';
    this.policy.vehicleDetails.push(new VehicleDetails('valueA1','valueA2'));
    this.policy.vehicleDetails.push(new VehicleDetails('valueB1','valueB2'));
    this.policy.vehicleDetails.push(new VehicleDetails('valueC1','valueC2'));
```

so, i am getting the value dynamically and i want to bind the values to the model as explained in the above code

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `constructor(private policynumber: string, private vinnumber: string)`. You define constructor parameters, but it's not clear what you expect to get passed and from where.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DI can't create an instance of `VehicleDetails` because it doesn't have any information about what to pass for `private policynumber: string, private vinnumber: string`

What you can do is to use the `@Inject()` decorator

```
constructor(@Inject('policy') private policynumber: string, @Inject('vin') private vinnumber: string) {
```

and provide the values like

```
providers: [Policy, VehicleDetails, {provide: 'policy', useValue: 'abc'}, {provide: 'vin', useValue: 'def'}],
```

Comment: If you use `new VehicleDetails(...)`, there is no need for `@Injectable()` or `VehicleDetails` in `providers: [Policy, VehicleDetails],`. Just remove these things and the error will be gone. Dependency injection is only for classes where Angulars DI creates instances for you.

Comment: when i remove the @Injectable(), i get the following error Can't resolve all parameters for VehicleDetails: (?, ?)

Comment: Did you also remove `VehicleDetails` from providers?

Comment: Do you have constructor parameters of type `VehicleDetails` in a component or service? You should only get this error if DI needs to inject a `VehicleDetails` instance somewhere. The code in your question doesn't show anything like that.

Comment: when i removed the @Injectable() from the VehicleDetails class and remove the VehicleDetails class from the @NGModule provider, i get the following error
Error: No provider for VehicleDetails!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152041/discussion-between-lijin-durairaj-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Please provide informations to **all** my questions. I don't know how to help without the information. > "You should only get this error if DI needs to inject a `VehicleDetails` instance somewhere. The code in your question doesn't show anything like that."

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `@Injectable` decorator according to your question update. Change your VehicleDetails to this:

```
export class VehicleDetails {
    constructor(policynumber: string, vinnumber: string) {
        this.policyNumber = policynumber,
            this.vinNumber = vinnumber
    }
    policyNumber: string;
    vinNumber: string;
}
```

and remove `VehicleDetails` from your `AppModule` providers.

Comment: i just removed the private but i am still getting the error

Comment: I missed the point in my answer that we can also Inject while using the providers. That is new to me, as I learned from @Gunter's answer.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj see Gunter's answer. That is what you need.

Comment: could you please see my latest updated comment, for a better understanding of my problem, thank you

Comment: according to your comment, there is no need for the @Injectable decorator, see my updated answer.